# How to interpret a negative failure rate?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, statistics, probability

In statistical engineering the "hazard rate" of a distribution is defined as:

$$r(x)=\frac{f(x)}{1-F(x)}$$

where $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ are the [PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) and [CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).  Basically $r(x)$ is the odds that, having reached a certain point on the abscissa (usually time), you won't get any further.  In the study of mechanical failure, the relevant distributions are those with an $r(x)$ that is everywhere increasing for positive x, like the Weibull distribution.

My question is how would you interpret an $r(x)$ whose absolute value is everywhere increasing for positive x, but which is negative?  Does the sign matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ have the necessary properties<sup>1</sup> then it should not be possible to get a negative value of $r(x)$.

A common place to get confused here using a different range for the PDF and the evaluation of the failure rate.

---

<sup>1</sup>

- $f(x)$ strictly non-negative over $[x_{min},x_{max})$
- $F(x) = \int_{x_{min}}^x \mathrm{d}u f(u)$ for $ x \in [x_{min},x_{max}) $
- $F(x)$ strictly non-negative over $[x_{min},x_{max})$ and  monotonically increasing with $F(x_{min})=0$ (these are implied by the earlier conditions) and $F(x_{max}) \le 1$. Note that this implies that you express $f$ and $F$ in fractional quantities and *never* in percent.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would expect, but I can't see where I'm going wrong.  Take the lognormal distribution for example.  For mean=0, standard dev>1.3 I get negative $r(x)$ for all positive $x$  (Acknowledge that the LN dist. would not be used in failure rate studies, still $r(x)$ should have some intelligible meaning for any distribution)

Comment: Wikipedia [shows the PDF and CDF as well behaved for those values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)... Any chance that you are messing up your evaluation of one or the other at zero?

Comment: Aha, it's that pesky constant of integration again.

Comment: (as is so often the case)

Comment: We have certainly all been there.